# Bijective mapping from $(-1,1)$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, continuity

I have read several times that $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x)= \frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

is an homeomorphism.

Therefore, it must be a bijection, but I'm stuck trying to prove it is injective and surjective.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Alexis. I didn't know how to get it like that.

Comment: are you sure for the function? I guess you mean $f(x)= \frac{x}{1-x^2}$ ...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Sorry. Have edited the question. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{x}{1-x^2}\\
&=\frac{1+x^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}\\
&\gt0\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
we get that $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is strictly monotone on $(-1,1)$ and continuous. Furthermore,
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{x}{1-x^2}=-\infty\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to+1}\frac{x}{1-x^2}=+\infty\tag{3}
$$
The [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), $(2)$, and $(3)$ say that $f$ attains every value between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. That is, $f$ is surjective.

The [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that if $x\ne y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$, then there is some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ so that $f'(\xi)=0$, which contradicts $(1)$. Therefore, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$. That is, $f$ is injective.

Comment: Great answer, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to prove that $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is invertible to prove that it is a bijection. We want to find an $x$ such that

$$y = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$$

for each $y\in\mathbb{R}$. We get that this is equivalent to

$$y(1-x^2) = x$$

$$yx^2 + x - y = 0$$

$$x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)x - 1 = 0$$

One can see that this quadratic in $x$ necessarily has two real roots, and furthermore that by Vieta's formulas the product of these roots is $-1$. Since they are not each $1$ and $-1$, we get that one of these roots lies outside the interval $(-1,1)$ while the other lies inside of it. Thus, the root inside the interval is our inverse $f^{-1}(y)$, and it is unique.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For any $0\neq y\in\mathbb{R}$, try solving $y= \frac{x}{1-x^2}\Leftrightarrow yx^2+x-y=0$ w.r.t. $x$. You will get:
$$
x_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}
$$
Notice that,

- if $y>0$ then $x_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}<-\frac{2y+1}{2y}<-1$,
  while
- if $y<0$ then $x_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2|y|}>\frac{2|y|+1}{2|y|}>1$

Thus, in any case $x_1$ lies outside $(-1,1)$. Consequently, for any $0\neq y\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a single value 
$$
x=x_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\in(-1,1)
$$
such that $y=f(x)$. This proves, that $f(x)$ is injective and surjective, thus bijective.

**Note:** Injectivity follows also by the fact that (by standard arguments, for example see the graph below) $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(-1,1)$ and thus $``1-1"$. 
[image: Graph of $f(=\frac{x}{1-x^2})$]

**P.S.:** Surjectivity is also obvious from the graph ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, your answer really helped me.