# Homeomorphism from (a,b) to reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

> Question:
>   Show that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$ then $\left ( a,b \right ) $ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

[Hint: Let 
$$f:\left( -1,1\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ \ \ f\left( x \right)=\frac{x}{ 1-x^{2} } ;$$ 
use standard results from calculus to prove continuity]

$f\left ( x \right )=\frac{x}{\left ( 1-x^{2} \right )}$
and the inverse is $f^{-1}\left ( x \right )=\frac{y}{1-y^{2}}$
every element in $\left ( a,b \right )$ is the image of exactly one element in $\mathbb{R}$.
We have bijection.

At this point, my lack of formal education in real analysis is posing some problems but let's give it a shot.

> Definition:
>   Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in$ A. 
>   We say that f is continuous at c if given any neighbourhood $V_{\varepsilon }\left ( f\left ( c \right ) \right )$ of $f\left ( c  \right )$ there exists a neighbourhood $V_{\delta }\left ( c \right )$ of c such that if x is any point of $A \cap V_{\delta}\left ( c \right )$, then
>   $f\left ( x \right )$ belongs to $V_{\varepsilon }\left ( f\left ( c \right ) \right )$

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you got $f^{-1}$ wrong. It's not defined at $\pm 1$.

Comment: If you know that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, $f$ is a homeomorphism from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This proves that $(-1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Then you can show that $(-1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(a,b)$ (by considering some linear homeomorphism, say $(-1,1)\ni x\mapsto a+(b-a)(x+1)/2\in (a,b)$). Composing, get a homeomorphis $(a,b)\leftrightarrow (-1,1)\leftrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The domain is the open interval (-1,1). There is no need to take into account x={-1,1}@JohnMa

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I need to first prove f and its inverse are continuous.

Comment: But the inverse should have domain $\mathbb R$. @Mathematicing

Comment: $f$ is continuous because it is obtained by adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, constants, and the identity, i.e., by composing continuous functions.

Comment: @Mathematicing It might be quite boring to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism. The inverse you got for $f$ does not work. However $f$ is an increasing continuous (it is given in terms of basic operations of the identify, which is continuous) bijection from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so common calculus results (intermediate value theorem) imply that it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse you are reporting in your post is wrong. Actually, the inverse function of
$$
f:\left( -1,1\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ \ \ f\left( x \right)=\frac{x}{ 1-x^{2} } 
$$
is given (see also: [Homeomorphism from open interval to  R](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1927402/195021)) by: 
$$
f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to (-1,1), \ \ \ f^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}, x\neq 0 \textrm{ and } f^{-1}(0)=0
$$
Both functions are continuous. This is also a fact from elementary calculus: all polynomial functions, rational functions (that is: quotients of polynomials), square roots and their sums, products, quotients and compositions are continuous on their domain. It also relatively easy (use Del'Hospital for example) to show the continuity of the inverse at the origin: 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\big(-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}\big)'}{(2x)'}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{1+4x^2})'}{2}= \\ 
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+4x^2)'}{4\sqrt{1+4x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{8x}{4\sqrt{1+4x^2}}=0
$$

Comment: In the link to another thread,
How did you conclude "$x_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}<-\frac{2y+1}{2y}<-1$"?

Comment: $y>0$ so $\sqrt{4y^2+1}>2y\Leftrightarrow -\sqrt{4y^2+1}<-2y\Leftrightarrow \frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}<-\frac{2y+1}{2y}<-1$

Comment: (Pedantry: $f^{-1}(x)$ is not a rational function.)

Comment: you are right! I will edit it. thanks.